# How can I partition a Perl array into equal sized chunks?

Tags: perl

I have a fixed-sized array where the size of the array is always in factor of 3.

```
my @array = ('foo', 'bar', 'qux', 'foo1', 'bar', 'qux2', 3, 4, 5);
```

How can I cluster the member of array such that we can get
an array of array group by 3:

```
$VAR = [ ['foo','bar','qux'],
         ['foo1','bar','qux2'],
         [3, 4, 5] ];
```

Comment: Watch out, all the splice based options below are destructive to your array.  You will need to work on a copy if you want to preserve your original array.

Comment: This is a very important note re: splice. 

Addedum: **natatime** is implemented using splice as well, so is subject to the above note.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
my @VAR;
push @VAR, [ splice @array, 0, 3 ] while @array;
```

or you could use [`natatime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::MoreUtils#natatime) from [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::MoreUtils)

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(natatime);

my @VAR;
{
  my $iter = natatime 3, @array;
  while( my @tmp = $iter->() ){
    push @VAR, \@tmp;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Brad - +1 for List::MoreUtils - it's a great gem all-around even outside of this answer.

Comment: Also, please note that - at least as of 2/2009 - there was a memory leak in XS version of natatime (no leak in PP version). See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=742364

Comment: In Perl 6 you could write it as `@array.rotor(3,0)`

Comment: The design for `.rotor` in Perl 6 has changed, you would just write it as `@array.rotor(3)`. If you need to get the last few elements when the list doesn't split evenly you would add a `:partial` to the method call.

Answer (score 6):

I really like List::MoreUtils and use it frequently.  However, I have never liked the `natatime` function.  It doesn't produce output that can be used with a for loop or `map` or `grep`.

I like to chain map/grep/apply operations in my code.  Once you understand how these functions work, they can be very expressive and very powerful.

But it is easy to make a function to work like natatime that returns a list of array refs.

```
sub group_by ($@) {
    my $n     = shift;
    my @array = @_;

    croak "group_by count argument must be a non-zero positive integer"
        unless $n > 0 and int($n) == $n;

    my @groups;
    push @groups, [ splice @array, 0, $n ] while @array;

    return @groups;
}
```

Now you can do things like this:

```
my @grouped = map [ reverse @$_ ],
              group_by 3, @array;
```

** Update re Chris Lutz's suggestions **

Chris, I can see merit in your suggested addition of a code ref to the interface.  That way a map-like behavior is built in.

```
# equivalent to my map/group_by above
group_by { [ reverse @_ ] } 3, @array;
```

This is nice and concise.  But to keep the nice `{}` code ref semantics, we have put the count argument `3` in a hard to see spot.

I think I like things better as I wrote it originally.

A chained map isn't that much more verbose than what we get with the extended API.
With the original approach a grep or other similar function can be used without having to reimplement it.

For example, if the code ref is added to the API, then you have to do:

```
my @result = group_by { $_[0] =~ /foo/ ? [@_] : () } 3, @array;
```

to get the equivalent of:

```
my @result = grep $_->[0] =~ /foo/,
             group_by 3, @array;
```

Since I suggested this for the sake of easy chaining, I like the original better.

Of course, it would be easy to allow either form:

```
sub _copy_to_ref { [ @_ ] }

sub group_by ($@) {
    my $code = \&_copy_to_ref;
    my $n = shift;

    if( reftype $n eq 'CODE' ) {
        $code = $n;
        $n = shift;
    }

    my @array = @_;

    croak "group_by count argument must be a non-zero positive integer"
        unless $n > 0 and int($n) == $n;

    my @groups;
    push @groups, $code->(splice @array, 0, $n) while @array;

    return @groups;
}
```

Now either form should work (untested).  I'm not sure whether I like the original API, or this one with the built in map capabilities better.

Thoughts anyone?

** Updated again **

Chris is correct to point out that the optional code ref version would force users to do:

```
group_by sub { foo }, 3, @array;
```

Which is not so nice, and violates expectations.  Since there is no way to have a flexible prototype (that I know of), that puts the kibosh on the extended API, and I'd stick with the original.

On a side note, I started with an anonymous sub in the alternate API, but I changed it to a named sub because I was subtly bothered by how the code looked.  No real good reason, just an intuitive reaction.  I don't know if it matters either way.

Comment: Why not have `group_by` take a code reference as the first argument, so we can determine what to do with our group? Usage: `group_by { [ @_ ] } 3, @array;`

Comment: Ideal syntax would be `group_by 3 { [ @_ ] } @array;` but of course we'd need to explicitly declare the anonymous `sub` for Perl not to whine.

Comment: The only problem with the second version that uses an optional code reference is that the `map { code } @list` syntax only works if the subroutine is prototyped to have the first argument be a code reference. As written, you would need to explicitly specify that the code block was a `sub` (or declare the sub somewhere else and pass a reference to it). Also, I wouldn't have bothered writing a named subroutine for `_copy_to_ref()` and just said `my $code = sub { [ @_ ] };` but that's just me. It might be more efficient to do it your way.

Comment: I agree about `natatime` offering a very limited (and a decidedly un-ModernPerl) API. No chaining, no easy iteration with counting, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Or this:

```
my $VAR;
while( my @list = splice( @array, 0, 3 ) ) {
    push @$VAR, \@list;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another answer (a variation on Tore's, using splice but avoiding the while loop in favor of more Perl-y map)

```
my $result = [ map { [splice(@array, 0, 3)] } (1 .. (scalar(@array) + 2) % 3) ];
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it more Perl-y just because it uses `map()` - it's largely much more cluttered and harder to grok. The most "Perl-y" solution is `natatime()` because it's from CPAN.

Comment: Hmm... I can't say I greatly disagree with you re: possibly harder to grok. But having been a professional Perl developer for many years, I have encountered enough bad-to-horrible junk on CPAN that I don't necessarily consider "uses something from CPAN" to be a Good Householding Seal Of Approval of a perl solution. Mind you,  List::MoreUtils, from my cursory examination today, appears to be a very neat and useful module, so it is definitely not included in the gripe above :)

Comment: @DVK - When I say "because it's from CPAN," I'm lovingly poking fun at the trends of my favorite language, not offering it as the be-all end-all of solutions. We really need to find a way to express sarcasm on the internets.

Comment: Sorry. After 2 sleepless nights, my sarcasm module is not loading.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$VAR = [map $_ % 3 == 0 ? ([ $array[$_], $array[$_ + 1], $array[$_ + 2] ]) 
                        : (),
            0..$#array];
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether +1 it for cuteness or -1 it for sheer hackiness :)  Unvoted it stays.

Comment: -1, because I would 100% make a mistake somewhere in there :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the spart function from the List::NSect package on CPAN.

```
    perl -e '
    use List::NSect qw{spart};
    use Data::Dumper qw{Dumper};
    my @array = ("foo", "bar", "qux", "foo1", "bar", "qux2", 3, 4, 5);
    my $var = spart(3, @array);
    print Dumper $var;
    '

    $VAR1 = [
          [
            'foo',
            'bar',
            'qux'
          ],
          [
            'foo1',
            'bar',
            'qux2'
          ],
          [
            3,
            4,
            5
          ]
        ];
```

Answer (score 3):

Another generic solution, non-destructive to the original array:

```
use Data::Dumper;

sub partition {
    my ($arr, $N) = @_; 

    my @res;
    my $i = 0;

    while ($i + $N-1 <= $#$arr) {
        push @res, [@$arr[$i .. $i+$N-1]];
        $i += $N; 
    }   

    if ($i <= $#$arr) {
        push @res, [@$arr[$i .. $#$arr]];
    }   
    return \@res;
}

print Dumper partition(
    ['foo', 'bar', 'qux', 'foo1', 'bar', 'qux2', 3, 4, 5], 
    3   
);
```

The output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'foo',
            'bar',
            'qux'
          ],
          [
            'foo1',
            'bar',
            'qux2'
          ],
          [
            3,
            4,
            5
          ]
        ];
```

Answer (score 3):

#### As a learning experience I decided to do this in Perl6

The first, perhaps most simplest way I tried was to use [`map`](http://doc.perl6.org/routine/map).

```bash
my @output := @array.map: -> $a, $b?, $c? { [ $a, $b // Nil, $c // Nil ] };
.say for @output;
```

```
foo bar qux
foo1 bar qux2
3 4 5
```

That didn't seem very scalable. What if I wanted to [take](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/gather%20take) the items from the list 10 at a time, that would get very annoying to write. ... Hmmm I did just mention ["take"](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/gather%20take) and there is a keyword named [`take`](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/gather%20take) lets try that in a subroutine to make it more generally useful.

```perl6
sub at-a-time ( Iterable \sequence, Int $n where $_ > 0 = 1 ){
  my $is-lazy = sequence.is-lazy;
  my \iterator = sequence.iterator;

  # gather is used with take
  gather loop {
    my Mu @current;
    my \result = iterator.push-exactly(@current,$n);

    # put it into the sequence, and yield
    take @current.List;

    last if result =:= IterationEnd;
  }.lazy-if($is-lazy)
}
```

For kicks let's try it against an infinite list of the fibonacci sequence

```perl6
my $fib = (1, 1, *+* ... *);
my @output = at-a-time( $fib, 3 );
.say for @output[^5]; # just print out the first 5
```

```
(1 1 2)
(3 5 8)
(13 21 34)
(55 89 144)
(233 377 610)
```

---

Notice that I used `$fib` instead of `@fib`. It was to prevent Perl6 from caching the elements of the Fibonacci sequence.
It might be a good idea to put it into a subroutine to create a new sequence everytime you need one, so that the values can get garbage collected when you are done with them.
I also used [`.is-lazy`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/is-lazy) and [`.lazy-if`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Iterable#method_lazy-if) to mark the output sequence lazy if the input sequence is. Since it was going into an array `@output` it would have tried to generate all of the elements from an infinite list before continuing onto the next line.

---

Wait a minute, I just remembered [`.rotor`](http://doc.perl6.org/routine/rotor).

```perl6
my @output = $fib.rotor(3);

.say for @output[^5]; # just print out the first 5
```

```
(1 1 2)
(3 5 8)
(13 21 34)
(55 89 144)
(233 377 610)
```

[`.rotor`](http://doc.perl6.org/routine/rotor) is actually far more powerful than I've demonstrated.

If you want it to return a partial match at the end you will need to add a [`:partial` to the arguments of `.rotor`](http://doc.perl6.org/routine/rotor).

Answer (score 1):

Below a more generic solution to the problem:

```
my @array = ('foo', 'bar', 1, 2);
my $n = 3;
my @VAR = map { [] } 1..$n;
my @idx = sort map { $_ % $n } 0..$#array;

for my $i ( 0..$#array ){
        push @VAR[ $idx[ $i ] ], @array[ $i ];
}
```

This also works when the number of items in the array is not a factor of 3. 
In the above example, the other solutions with e.g. `splice` would produce two arrays of length 2 and one of length 0.