# Perl - Split Array in to Smaller Evenly Distributed Arrays

Tags: arrays, perl

How would I split a Perl array of arbitrary size in to a variable number of smaller arrays with the number of elements in each smaller array being distibuted as evenly possible? The original array must not be destroyed.

Comment: WHat does "as evenly as possible" mean? An array of size 11 could be split into 5,6  or  4,4,3   or 2,2,2,2,2,1

Comment: It means exactly what you posted in the examples you gave. The first if 2 arrays are required, the second if three arrays are required and the last one if six arrays are required.

Comment: Here may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490896/how-can-i-partition-a-perl-array-into-equal-sized-chunks  As to my above point. You have to decide how to split up the array i.e. 4,4,3  4,3,4 or 3,4,4. Does it matter which way?

Comment: The size of the array is always a factor of 3 in that example rather than an arbitrary sized array. It does not matter which way the array is split up.

Comment: [natatime](http://p3rl.org/List::MoreUtils#natatime)

Comment: natatime uses splice which would destroy the original array. Therefore, it fails in regard to the condition of preserving the original array.

Comment: The original array is not destroyed, you didn't actually run the code.

Comment: I thought of `natatime` initially, but couldn't come with anything substantially better than doing the whole thing by hand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper; # for debugging only 

print Dumper(distribute(7, [1..30]));

# takes number+arrayref, returns ref to array of arrays
sub distribute {
    my ($n, $array) = @_;

    my @parts;
    my $i = 0;
    foreach my $elem (@$array) {
        push @{ $parts[$i++ % $n] }, $elem;
    };
    return \@parts;
};
```

This guarantees that number of elements in @parts may only differ by one. There's anonther solution that would count the numbers beforehand and use splicing:

```
push @parts, [ @$array[$offset..$offset+$chunk] ];
$offset += chunk;
# alter $chunk if needed.
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version using List::MoreUtils:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw(part);

use Data::Dumper;

my @array = 1..9;
my $partitions = 3;

my $i = 0;

print Dumper part {$partitions * $i++ / @array} @array;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care what winds up in each array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw(part);
use Data::Dumper;

my $i = 0;
my $numParts = 2;
my @part = part { $i++ % $numParts } 1 .. 30; 
print Dumper @part;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Dallaylaen's answer doesn't quite work because you can't pass an array into a subroutine in Perl.  Instead of passing in an array (or a list as Dallaylaen did in his example) you must pass in a reference to an array:

```
    my @arrayIn = (1..30);
    my @arrayOfArrays = distribute(7, \@arrayIn);
    sub distribute {
        my ($n, $array) = @_;

        my @parts;
        my $i = 0;
        foreach my $elem (@$array) {
            push @{ $parts[$i++ % $n] }, $elem;
        };
        return @parts;
    };
```