# Pulling a group of ranges in a string or array

Tags: perl

I have an array and a group value which might change:

```
@array = ("The","quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog");
$group = 3;
```

The results I'm trying to return are:

```
The
The quick
The quick brown

quick
quick brown
quick brown fox
```

In other words, starting at the first element & grouping words up to $group value. I want to iterate through the string word boundaries (or array elements) to gather those groups combinations. I've tried various regex combos, slices and shifts without success. I *think* I need a combo of regex & shifting (or MAP [above my head]).

Any suggestions on the construct appreciated!

Comment: You might want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490896/how-can-i-partition-a-perl-array-into-equal-sized-chunks

Answer (score 4):

Once you have your data in the array, a solution is rather simple:

```
use List::Util qw/min/;
use 5.010;
my @words = (...);
my $group = 3;

for my $i (0 .. $#words) {
  # finding the maximum index for the slice
  for my $j ($i .. min($i + $group - 1, $#words)) {
    say join " ", @words[$i .. $j];
  }
}
```

How you handle the rest when there are less than `$group` elements left is unspecified in your question, you could also break out of the loop in that case.

Actually getting the words of a string is a somewhat hard problem. The easiest sensible solution is to split on non-word characters:

```
my @words = split /\W+/, $string;
```

Comment: Absolutely what I was looking for. I had trouble defining $j in your example as I'm not familiar with min/max. Thank you!