# Perl store to new array once the number of elements limit reach in one array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array in the format:

```
@arr = ABHCKPDLT OJEWFNONP POJEWPOFJ IWOJEFPPW IHWEF_IPIA
```

I need to check is the number of elements limit say 4k characters, is reached. If so, a new array has to be created and store next limit of arrays.

```
@arr_final = [[ABHCKPDLT OJEWFNONP POJEWPOFJ],[IWOJEFPPW IHWEF_IPIA]]

 #!usr/bin/perl
 use List::MoreUtils qw(natatime);
 my @VAR;
 {
  my $iter = natatime 3, @arr;
  while( my @tmp = $iter->() ){
    push @VAR, \@tmp;
  }
 }
```

Please suggest what would be best approach in perl.

Comment: Please, show real code, not a random syntax that doesn't work in Perl. Do you have an array, or an array of arrays? What should happen to the old array when a new one is created?

Comment: Old array has to be updated as the one in @arr_final. I have an array and I need array of arrays. I am beginner and have used as per suggestion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490896/how-can-i-partition-a-perl-array-into-equal-sized-chunks but doesn't work

Comment: @Neetu: Please show us your actual code.

Comment: @Neetu When you click on the "edit" link below the question you'll be able to change it -- please add your code that shows how you attempt this.  Saying "_but doesn't work_" just does not help at all.

Comment: Something is still unclear. You're using `natatime()` to extract three elements at a time from your array. So where does the 4K character limitation come in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the character count in a variable, reset it when starting a new subarray.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $THRESHOLD = 15;

my @arr = qw( 123456789 123456 123456789 132 123456789 1234 123456789 12345 1234567890 );

my @final = ([]);
my $size = 0;
while (@arr) {
    $size += length $arr[0];
    if ($size > $THRESHOLD) {
        $size = length $arr[0];
        push @final, [];
    }
    push @{ $final[-1] }, shift @arr;
}
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you @choroba. This is of great help. 

Print statement : `print "@$_\n" for @final;`